# SQL: Como sumar una fila de dos columnas declaradas?

Tags: sql

Hola estoy tratando de armar un query que sume la misma fila dos columnas pero que lo acabo de declarar:

```
Select 
Count(perro) as totalperros,
Count(gato) as totalgatos,
totalperros + total gatos as Totalambos

From animales
```

Cual es la forma correcta de encontrar el totalambos?

Comment: La mayoria de las bases de datos, etiquetan las columnas una vez terminado el query (algunas te permiten usar las etiquetas antes)... si queres sumar esas columnas en el mismo query, basta con hacer: count(perros)+ count(gatos)

Answer (score 2):

la forma correcta de encontrar "totalambos" podría ser:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(perro) AS totalperros,
COUNT(gato) AS totalgatos,
COUNT(perro) + COUNT(gato) AS totalambos
FROM animales;
```

Esta solución puedo asegurarte que funciona en MySQL o PostgreSQL. No estoy totalmente seguro pero creo que no se esta saliendo del estándar de SQL, por lo que debería funcionar en cualquier motor que sea adapte a este.